# Java 8 extract all keys from matching values in a Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm relatively new to Java8 and I have a scenario where I need to retrieve all the keys from the Map which matched with the objects.

Wanted to know if there is a way to get all keys without iterating them from the list again.

```
Person.java
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
//setters and getters & constructor


MAIN Class.

String inputCriteriaFirstName = "john";   

Map<String, Person> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
Collection<Person> personCollection = inputMap.values();
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(personCollection);
List<Person> personOutputList = personList.stream()
.filter(p -> p.getFirstName().contains(inputCriteriaFirstName ))
.collect(Collectors.toList());


//IS There a BETTER way to DO Below ??

Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
for(Person person : personOutputList) {
    keys.addAll(inputMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), person))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
inputMap.entrySet() 
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> personOutputList.contains(entry.getValue()))
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new))
```

Comment: Why use `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)` instead of `Collectors.toSet()`, as was used in the question?

Comment: @Andreas `Collectors.toSet` returns an undefined Set ( may be immutable ), while the OP wanted a `HashSet` exactly

Comment: I don't see that OP wanted a `HashSet` **exactly**. I see that OP wants a `Set` (see `Set<String> keys`), and that OPs attempt is creating a `HashSet` for the purpose, but I don't see any requirement that it *must* be a `HashSet`.

Comment: Hi Eugene; what do you think the answer provided by Andreas below?

Comment: @Andreas well I inferred that from `Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();` thinking that he wants guarantees to be a mutable `Set`. If that would have been a properly coded method that returns a `Set`, I would have not said that

Answer (score 7):

Instead of iterating over all the entries of the Map for each `Person`, I suggest iterating over the Map once:

```
Set<String> keys =
     inputMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .filter(e -> personOutputList.contains(e.getValue()))
             .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

This would still result in quadratic running time (since `List.contains()` has linear running time). You can improve that to overall linear running time if you create a `HashSet` containing the elements of `personOutputList`, since `contains` for `HashSet` takes constant time.

You can achieve that by changing

```
List<Person> personOutputList = 
    personList.stream()
              .filter(p -> p.getFirstName().contains(inputCriteriaFirstName))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to

```
Set<Person> personOutputSet = 
    personList.stream()
              .filter(p -> p.getFirstName().contains(inputCriteriaFirstName))
              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Comment: small nitpick: OP wants a `HashSet`, `Collectors.toSet` does not guarantee that...

Comment: @Eugene fair enough

Comment: also we might both be very wrong here for a certain case where `e.getValue` returns a null and in future the OP might have `List.of(..)` for `personOutputList`, thus this failing with a `NullPointer`, just a thought

Comment: @Eugene It makes little sense to me to have null values in that Map, so I don't see a need to account for such possibility.

Comment: *generally* I could not agree more. But may be there is some sense in OP using `Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), person)`...

Comment: Thanks, Eran and Eugene. I will put necessary checks for an empty list and check for variables in the case of NullPointer as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use **foreach** api provided in java8 under lambda's

Below is code for your main method :

```
public static  void main() {

        String inputCriteriaFirstName = "john";   

        Map<String, Person> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();

        inputMap.forEach((key,value) -> {
            if(value.getFirstName().contains(inputCriteriaFirstName)){
                keys.add(key);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: not the most stylish approach, but the least expensive, only O(n).

Comment: @arthur the least expensive one would be to use a `for` loop. If you only care for `O(n)`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330345/2711488) is `O(n)` too and it only differs in memory complexity due to also providing the `personOutputList`. If the OP doesn’t need it, it would be easy to simplify the solution to a “stylish” approach having the same complexity as this `forEach` approach.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want a `personOutputList` with all the selected persons, and a `keys` set with the keys for those selected persons?

Best (for performance) option is to not discard the keys during search, then split the result into separate person list and key set.

Like this:

```
String inputCriteriaFirstName = "john";
Map<String, Person> inputMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Person> tempMap = inputMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getFirstName().contains(inputCriteriaFirstName))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
List<Person> personOutputList = new ArrayList<>(tempMap.values());
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>(tempMap.keySet());
```

The `keys` set is explicitly made an updatable copy. If you don't need that, drop the copying of the key values:

```
Set<String> keys = tempMap.keySet();
```